# mongodb update value in 3 level nested array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I want to update flag in array of objects which are 3 levels deep nested.

I have this array of ages:

```
[20, 25]
```

I want to set `flag: 1` for those users which has `type: students` and `ages: 20 or 25`

**Here is my Users collection:**

```
{
    "_id": "wef324DGSshf",
    "userTypes": [
        {
            "type": "students",
            "users": [
                {
                    "name": "John",
                    "age": 20,
                    "flag": 0
                },
                {
                    "name": "Mike",
                    "age": 25,
                    "flag": 0
                }
            ]
            
        },
        {
            "type": "students",
            "users": [
                {
                    "name": "Henry",
                    "age": 40,
                    "flag": 0
                },
                {
                    "name": "Nick",
                    "age": 25,
                    "flag": 0
                }
            ]
            
        },
        {
            "type": "teachers",
            "users": [
                {
                    "name": "Kim",
                    "age": 20,
                    "flag": 0
                },
                {
                    "name": "Charles",
                    "age": 25,
                    "flag": 0
                }
            ]
            
        }
    ]
}
```

After update I expect this response:

```
{
    "_id": "wef324DGSshf",
    "userTypes": [
        {
            "type": "students",
            "users": [
                {
                    "name": "John",
                    "age": 20,
                    "flag": 1
                },
                {
                    "name": "Mike",
                    "age": 25,
                    "flag": 1
                }
            ]
            
        },
        {
            "type": "students",
            "users": [
                {
                    "name": "Henry",
                    "age": 40,
                    "flag": 0
                },
                {
                    "name": "Nick",
                    "age": 25,
                    "flag": 1
                }
            ]
            
        },
        {
            "type": "teachers",
            "users": [
                {
                    "name": "Kim",
                    "age": 20,
                    "flag": 0
                },
                {
                    "name": "Charles",
                    "age": 25,
                    "flag": 0
                }
            ]
            
        }
    ]
}
```

What I have tried so far is this query:

```
Users.update(
    { "userTypes.users.age": { $in: [20,25] } },
    { "$set": { "userTypes.users.$.flag": "1" } }
);
```

My solution is not updating the  desired records, can anyone help me with the right query for this case?

Comment: Users.update({},
{
  "$set": {
    "userTypes.$[ut].users.$[user].flag": 1
  }
},
{
  arrayFilters: [
    {
      "ut.type": "students"
    },
    {
      "user.age": {
        $in: [
          20,
          25
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  multi: true
})

Comment: See it works [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/_cB8dzXTG8j)

Comment: For some reason my schema says: Error: userTypes.$[ut].users.$[user].flag is not allowed by the schema